# How to implement dependent library of Android Studio Package into Python?

Tags: python, java, android, kotlin

I want to start create Android Library / Application with Python, How to import Android's Library to Python Script? And how to render to make APK or JAR/AAR Library? QPython

I found the way by using some python plugins like QPython, Termux. But it is not an IDE but an Editor. Can I import Android Libraries like Java/Kotlin in Visual Studio, but with Python language?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best with specific programming questions. As written your question seems to lack background information about Android development details/limitations and its relation to various Python related projects. I don't see any details of what your tried/explored. Asking for opinions is also off-topic. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may be better of asking in a forum/discord/slack/reddit group/social media site.

Comment: Python is a very uncommon programming language for Android and unless in the end you have a bunch of .so files it will not integrate into Android Studio. Most likely implementing an Android library with python will take you more time than simply learning Kotlin.

Comment: I also insist on to continue with kotlin or java which are native for Android. You might also to take a look to Flutter and Android compose. In case you want to utilize some existing Python code, you can use Chaquopy for this.

Comment: Im happy with your answer, it seems that it is not easy to develop Android with Python. Thank you All.